# Unity crashes if there are more than 4 terrains

Tags: unity, 3d

please can you help me with the issue that I face, that is, I decided to create open-world game by creating several terrains and connect them together in Unity and firstly respective size of the terrains was 500X500 then I decided to add more terrains to make game world bigger and once I added the 5th terrain in the scene, Unity simply crashed. Later, I thought what if I increase the sizes of terrains rather than create more new terrains then the sizes of originally created terrains were changed from 500X500 to 800X800 and again Unity crashed. Please guys help me out with that and how to overcome that and I am just trying to create game without using any ready plugins and, say, try to create the game on my own. Thank you for your attention))).

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly trying to create an open-world, you shouldn't have an entire map in a single scene (at least in my experience) - without various camera rendering techniques. Unity offers a few ways to get around this need for complex algo's, the simplest being: [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAdditiveAsync.html)

Other methods would involve 'stitching' I don't know if that's the technical term, but it's what I've used for many years. Quick search reveals: [this post on reddit, with a 'stitcher' script](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/6qzsgm/how_to_handle_large_terrains_open_world/)

There are many more ways of combating this, probably too many to mention, but these should be a good starting point.

I'd recommend **not** buying a new PC... Just research tried and tested methods of loading, rather than dump it all in a single scene.

Comment: it would improve your answer if instead of posting links, you'd post their contents and why they are helpful, and then include the link. That way your answer will be useful for future readers if the link gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a "chunk" system, in which it generates terrain around the player, and then unloads/loads terrain when its close to the player, a good example if you've ever played it, is Minecraft. Which uses a chunk system to load and unload chunks of 16x16 blocks around the player, this way you can have unlimited terrain but it will never be loaded in all at once.

I can't explain how to do this on Stack, since that isn't really what it's meant for, but there are many chunk tutorials on YouTube that explain how to do it pretty well.